# Proving that $G$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G:=\{ (p,q) | p,q\in \mathbb{Q} , \ p^2-2q^2\neq 0\}$ and define binary operation $(p,q) \circ (r,s) =(pr+2qs, \ ps+qr)$ for $(p,q),(r,s) \in G.$
> Prove that $G$ is a group.

I could prove (i)～(iii).

(i) Binary operation is defined.

(ii) By calculation, I can see $(p,q) \circ ((r,s) \circ (t,u))=((p,q) \circ (r,s)) \circ (t,u)$ for $(p,q),(r,s),(t,u) \in G$.

(iii) Identity element is $(1,0)$ and if $(p,q) \circ (r,s)=(r,s) \circ (p,q)=(p,q)$ for all $(p,q) \in G$, then $(r,s)=(1,0).$

But I couldn't prove the existence of inverse element.

$(p,q) \circ (r,s) =(pr+2qs, \ ps+qr)$ so I should solve
$pr+2qs=1, ps+qr=0$.

Because $q=\dfrac{1-pr}{2s}$, $\quad ps+\dfrac{1-pr}{2s} r =0$. I couldn't solve this.

How can I find $r$ and $s$ ?

Comment: Hint: $pr+2qs = 1$ and $qr+ps=0$ is a system of two linear equations in two unknowns. It will definitely have a solution (for $r$ and $s$, provided that the matrix of the system is not singular; that is, it has nonzero determinant. Under what conditions will the matrix have zero determinant?

Answer (score 3):

We can identify $(p,q)$ with $p+q\sqrt2$, whereupon $\circ$ becomes ordinary multiplication. Then
$$\frac1{p+q\sqrt2}=\frac{p-q\sqrt2}{p^2-2q^2}$$
and the inverse of $(p,q)$ is $\frac1{p^2-2q^2}(p,-q)$.